# USB device linux enumeration changes while in operation

Tags: linux, usb, libusb, lsusb

I have to push firmware files to multiple usb devices  (2 files per device) via ymodem file transfer. However just before uploading the files the device needs to be rebooted to get access to the file transfer menu. Once it reboots the port that it gets assigned to is no longer the same - due to re-enumeration. As a result trying to open the port, that it was originally assigned to transfer the file gives an error. Is there a way around this or perhaps have a dedicated port for each device???

Thanks,
Archie

Comment: Check `ID_PATH` from `udevadm info`. It should not change unless hubs are reset and re-enumerated.

Comment: Thanks @dimich. that worked.... grep'ing either with DEVPATH or ID_PATH will give the info that I am looking for. Thanks again.